# Convert System.Drawing.Font to PdfSharp.Drawing.XFont

Tags: c#, fonts, pdfsharp

How to properly create XFont object that has correspondent size to Font.Size?
I have XGraphics, System.Drawing.Font with FontFamily "Tahoma" and size 6.
When I create XFont like in example, I get very big text on rendered PDF page.
I presume that Font.Size iz Points unit, and XFont needs to be created with "emSize".

```
    void PDFCreateObjectOnLabel(XGraphics graphics, ObjectBase formatObject, string objectText)
    {
       XStringFormat objFormat = new XStringFormat();
       objFormat.Alignment = XStringAlignment.Center;
       XFont xFont = new XFont(formatObject.Font.FontFamily.Name, formatObject.Font.Size);
       graphics.DrawString(objectText, xFont, someBrush, someRect, objFormat);
    }
```

When I try to create XFont like this:

```
XFont xFont = new XFont(new Font(formatObject.Font.FontFamily.Name, formatObject.Font.Size, formatObject.Font.Style));
```

I get Exception "Font must use GraphicsUnit.World."
When I try to pass GraphincUnit.World, I get very large text.
Parameter "formatObject" is passed from another assemly and it is not my code. Font object in "formatObject" holds Unit type "Point".

Comment: are you try : ```new XFont(fontObj as Font);``` ?

Comment: I get an error about using "World" units

Comment: mentioned method worked perfectly for me, what about this one ```new XFont(new Font("Tahoma" , 6 , FontStyle.Regular));``` ?

Comment: I get Font object from another assembly, it is not controlled by my code. That Font's Unit is "Point". Whe I use contructor like in your previous comment, I get Exception "Font must use GraphicsUnit.World.". When I pass a GraphicsUnit.World in Font constructor, I get very large text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the right font size like in code example:

```
        double emSize = formatObject.Font.Size * 0.35277777777778;//1 point (computer) = 0.35277777777778 millimeter [mm]
        XFont xFont = new XFont(new Font(formatObject.Font.FontFamily.Name, (float)emSize, formatObject.Font.Style, GraphicsUnit.World));
```